# IIS FTP Server works locally, but cannot connect from remote

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, ftp

I'm trying to setup an FTP server on Windows 2008 Server.  I can connect locally:

```
C:\>ftp localhost
Connected to WebHead1
220 Microsoft FTP Service
```

However, when I try to connect from remote, it doesn't work:

```
~>ftp x.x.x.x
ftp: Can't connect to `x.x.x.x': Operation timed out
ftp: Can't connect to `x.x.x.x'
```

I've tried everything I can think of with the settings.  The FTP server is bound to all unassigned IPs and listening on port 21.  I've also checked "FTP Server" in the firewall settings.  Nothing appears in the FTP log files.  I'm totally out of ideas!

Comment: Gents, I've attempted the advice you had here to discover that Passive mode is enabled if you go to Firewall Support for the FTP site. If you enter the public IP address in the Firewall Support, it will enable Passive Mode for the FTP site. If you remove the IP address from Firewall Support, it will start working. You will need to make sure to check both the server level and the ftp site level.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Figured it out.  The issue is documented [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121026023711/http://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/524831/default-ftp-firewall-port-21-rule-is-broken-in-windows-2008-r2).

Basically, you have to run:

```
sc sidtype ftpsvc unrestricted
```

And then restart the FTP service:

```
net stop ftpsvc & net start ftpsvc
```

From what I can tell, it's a bug in R2.  Go figure.

Comment: Confirmed as working for Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8...

Comment: I can confirm the exact same issue occurs in Server 2012 IIS and this solution fixes it.

Comment: This solution works for Windows Pro 7 FTP Server. thanks.

Comment: Confirmed still necessary in Aug '15, and has worked for me.

Comment: Confirmed and is working. I had this issue on Windows server 2012 and IIS 8. Used the above commands and ftp is now working fine. Thanks for sharing buddy :)

Comment: This helped me as well. The link to the issue documentation isn't working, though.

Comment: Confirmed on 2012 R2, this got it working

Comment: didn't solve the problem. any other advice?

Comment: Wow. This is amazing. Windows Server 2016 Standard worked

Comment: Confirmed worked for IIS10 on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: If you get `Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'unrestricted'`, use `sc.exe`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33785483/21115).

Comment: Didnt solve the problem.