# Windows Server 2012 R2 FTP server "closed by remote host"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ftp

I'm trying to host a FTP server from my WS 2012 R2. I did all the IIS stuff, disabled stateful as well. Port 20 and 21 are open. Current situation:

- From the machine: `ftp > open localhost` works
- From the machine: `ftp > open <ip address>` doesn't, "closed by remote host" right after connection
- From my PC: FileZilla "Connection closed by server" after 3 seconds of "Connection established, waiting for welcome message..."
- Local IP (`ipconfig`) is the same as external IP, thus no need for a firewall

I'm really noob in server stuff. If you need more info then ask away. Also, [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/438314/iis-ftp-server-works-locally-but-cannot-connect-from-remote) didn't help me at all.

Comment: Sounds like windows firewall is blocking port 21. Have you tried running wf.msc and adding port 21 to the inbound list?

Comment: @Joe It is in the inbound list, TCP 21, all profile, any. I used an online port checker and 21 is open. I also have TCP 20 in outbound.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating another rule to allow port 21 inbound.  I had the same problem with the default rule not working correctly. I believe it has to do with the fact the default rule includes a service/program rule.

[image]
[[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]